# Insert in database ONLY after checking username & Email availability

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a sign up form, user shouldn't be allowed to register if username/email is taken.

so before inserting user info and accepting the sign up, I am checking 2 major conditions 
1. If username is taken
2. If email is registered before

and then only the registration can go through.

I am using Ajax to send the data to php, but the data won't be inserted in the db for some reason (NO ERRORS SHOW!)

Where am I going wrong?

HTML code:

```
  <form method="post" role="form" id="register-form" autocomplete="off" action="includes/check_signup.php">

         <div class="form-header">
            <h3 class="form-title"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</h3>

         <div class="pull-right">
             <h3 class="form-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></h3>
         </div>

         </div>

         <div class="form-body">

              <!-- json response will be here -->
              <div id="errorDiv"></div>
              <!-- json response will be here -->

              <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" maxlength="40" autofocus="true" onBlur="checkname();">
                   </div>
                   <span class="help-block" id="error error-username"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" onBlur="checkemail();">
                   </div> 
                   <span class="help-block" id="error error-email"></span>                     
              </div>

              <div class="row">

                   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>  
                        <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                    
                   </div>

                   <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                        <input name="cpassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password">
                        </div>  
                        <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>                    
                   </div>

             </div>


            </div>

            <div class="form-footer">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn-signup" name="signup">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign Me Up
                 </button>
            </div>
            <p id='result'></p>

            </form>
```

Ajax code:

```
//check username availability
function checkname() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "includes/check_signup.php",
        data:'username='+$("#name").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#error").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}

function checkemail()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "includes/check_signup.php",
        data:'email='+$("#email").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#error").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}



$('document').ready(function()
                    {
    // name validation
    var nameregex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validname", function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || nameregex.test( value );
    }); 

    // valid email pattern
    var eregex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    $.validator.addMethod("validemail", function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || eregex.test( value );
    });

    $("#register-form").validate({

        rules:
        {
            name: {
                required: true,
                validname: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                validemail: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "check-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $( "#email" ).val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            cpassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#password'
            },
        },
        messages:
        {
            name: {
                required: "Username is required",
                validname: "Username can be a combination of Alphabets & Numbers",
                minlength: "your username is too short"
            },
            email : {
                required : "Email is required",
                validemail : "Please enter valid email address",
                remote : "Email already exists"
            },
            password:{
                required: "Password is required",
                minlength: "Password at least have 5 characters"
            },
            cpassword:{
                required: "Retype your password",
                equalTo: "Password did not match !"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    }); 


});





$('#register-form').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('#btn-signup').click(function(){
    $.post( 
        $('#register-form').attr('action'),
        $('#register-form :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

function name (){
    global $connection;
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['username'];

        $checkdata="SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName='$name' ";

        $query=mysqli_query($connection, $checkdata);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
        {
            echo "User Name is taken";
            return true;
        }

        exit();
    }
}

function email () {
    global $connection;
    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $emailId=$_POST['email'];

        $checkdata=" SELECT * FROM users WHERE userEmail='$emailId' ";

        $query=mysqli_query($connection, $checkdata);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
        {
            echo "Email Already Exist";
            return true;
        }

        exit();
    }
}

function insert_db (){
    global $connection;
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $pass = trim($_POST['cpassword']);
    $full_name = strip_tags($name);
    $user_email = strip_tags($email);
    $user_pass = strip_tags($pass);

    // sha256 password hashing
    $hashed_password = hash('sha256', $user_pass);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(userName,userEmail,userPassword) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$hashed_password')";

    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query); 

    if ($result) {
        echo "You have been registered";
        return true;
    } else {
        die ("error". mysqli_error ($connection));
    }

}

if (name()) {

} elseif (email()) {

} else {
    insert_db;
}
```

Comment: You got a variable sitting at the bottom all by itself.  Sure you didn't mean that to be a function call?

Comment: Please add the ajax call code.

Comment: why don't you just use the one query?

Comment: @Ayush I added it

Comment: @SymeonQuimby just noticed, thanks. but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- You mean one sql query?

Comment: sure. If you want to check if either username or email is taken, use an `OR` operator in one query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, thanks, I think I can do that. Sadly it won't solve my issue

Comment: look at your developer console for the js stuff and use php's error reporting. Might also check for errors on the queries also.

Comment: and this `else {
    insert_db;` it's missing the brackets `else {
    insert_db();` probably why the insert doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you're closing php tag and the code after it's never going to be executed.

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?> function name (){
```

You're exiting the script when calling function name() when there is no result in db, just use a return false; instead of exit();

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
        echo "User Name is taken";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Remove all the exit() from the script first of all, and replace it with return false.

```
if (name()) { #this will return false

} elseif (email()) { #after you removed exit() this should return false

} else {
    insert_db(); #fix the call 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed to copy the complete code. I think its from the way I call the functions.

Comment: I did that as you suggested, but now whenever I enter a taken username, it tries to insert the complete data in the db

Comment: Well... at least you're getting something right? You should now check your business logic. Fix the elseif.

Comment: I agree Catalin, I am getting closer. But u know what, I feel that could be done better using jQuery itself. I am trying there